# How to get next date time start from 12:00:00 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I'm looping the date to get past 50 days date!!
but the problem is I only want the current date time as the current time and next from there all date time I want as 12:00:00 !!
[image]

```
    const dates = [];
    const today = dayjs(new Date());
    for (let d = 0; d < 50; d++) {
      dates.push(today.subtract(d, "day"));
    }
    console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const dates = [];
const date = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  if (i !== 0) {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + i);
    currentDate.setHours(12, 0, 0);
  }
  dates.push(currentDate);
}
console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const dates = [];

for (let d = 0; d < 50; d++) {
  const date = new Date()

  if (d !== 0) {
    date.setHours(12, 0, 0)
  }

  dates.push(date)


}

console.log(dates);
```

Comment: But it gives me the first date time as 12:00:00 also but I want the current date time as current time and all other as 12:00:00 which we are getting here ! please help me